# How to define :validates to only allow the integers 1 and -1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this in my model:

```
validates :polarity, presence: true
```

I only want to allow `1` and `-1` (since it is a voting system).

How to achieve that?

Comment: try: `validates :polarity, presence: true, inclusion: { in: [-1, 1] }`

Comment: @apneadiving Thanks, it worked. Post an answer so I can check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in comments:

```
validates :polarity, presence: true, inclusion: { in: [-1, 1] }
```